# In proper HTML, must an <input> be in a <form>?

Tags: html, forms, input, standards, specifications

I need a few input elements, but their values won't be submitted anywhere - they're just going to be manipulated by some client-side JavaScript. Do I have to place them in a `<form>` to have legit HTML, or can they just be free-standing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is <input> well formed without a <form>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294572/is-input-well-formed-without-a-form)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For additional information, in xhtml strict you have to place  in one of these elements:  "ins", "del", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "p", "div", "address", "fieldset"

Answer (score 17):

No. You only need a form if you're submitting to a server.