# Pass database variables to jQuery via element attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any specification for "Pass database variables to jQuery via element attribute?"

I've been doing this for a long time:

```
<script>
   var status = <%= status %>;
</script>
```

I would much rather do something like this:

```
<variable data-name="status" data-value="<%= status %>" />
```

Then get it with jquery:

```
var status = $('variable[data-name="status"]').attr("data-value");
```

I would need the element to be hidden from displaying. I know there is a pattern for this, I just don't know what it's called or how to search it.

Comment: I like the most the way you were doing it for a long time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

`<input type="hidden" data-name="status" data-value="<%= status %>" />`

Comment: `input` without `form` sounds like bad HTML, no?

Comment: Nope it's completely fine. 

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568660/is-there-any-danger-to-using-input-fields-outside-without-forms-in-html-javascri

Comment: If you're using a hidden input anyway, why not `name="status" value="<%=status%>"`? Or `id="status"`, and the jQuery code would just be `$("#status").val()`...