# Input text field auto-complete (auto-fill), doesn't work as expected on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have a webpage with an email text field, that is not inside a `<form>` tag, like so:

```
<input id="email" label="False" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="required" type="email" value="">
```

I'm using the latest Chrome (v35) and I've previously entered an email that is "example@domain.com" (for the sake of the explanation).

The problem is this:
When I reload my webpage, click on the email text field and start typing "exa", an auto-complete box pops-up with "example@domain.com".
If I move the mouse cursor over the suggestion, without clicking it, the text field shows the "example@domain.com" inside it. When I move the cursor away from the suggestion box, the text field still shows the full email address.

Why is that a problem? Because when I try to read the value of the text field using jQuery or vanilla javascript, I get "exa", instead of "example@domain.com".

```
$("#email").val(); // returns "exa"
```

If I envelope the input text field inside a `<form>` tag, the problem described above, doesn't occur - the auto-completed text disappears from the input field when the mouse cursor moves away from it, so the text field and the value reading is in sync.

```
<form><input id="email" label="False" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="required" type="email" value=""></form>
```

I've created [a JSFiddle with a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HEdgc/3/).

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568660/is-there-any-danger-to-using-input-fields-outside-without-forms-in-html-javascri), a an input field can work perfectly outside a `<form>` tag.

I've tested it on Firefox, and everything works well.

So why is that?

Comment: Can you post your code .. May be via jsfiddle or codepen.io .. this will be better than guessing.

Comment: Interesting to note: if you place a word without the `@`in the second input that is wrapped in the form and hit enter, you will get the message "Please include an '@'...". This doesn't occur for the first input.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use `autocomplete="off"` attribute in input field. This one works fine for me on chrome

```
<input id="email" label="False" name="email" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off" required="required" type="email" value="">
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HEdgc/4/)