# <form method="link" > or <a>? What's the difference?

Tags: html, forms, get

I [saw](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/buttons/article.php/3478871) that we can write:

```
<form method="link" action="foo.html" >
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

To make a "link button".

But I know we can write:

```
<a href="foo.html" ><input type="button" /></a>
```

Which will do the same.

What's the difference? What's their browser compatibility?

Comment: If you're making a link that happens to look like a button, that seems like a job for CSS.

Comment: Using `<input>` outside of a `<form>` is invalid HTML as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @Adrian - It is actually [legal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53221899/5247200).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That page you link to is incorrect. There is no `link` value for the `method` attribute in HTML. This will cause the form to fall back to the default value for the method attribute, `get`, which is equivalent to an anchor element with a `href` attribute anyway, as both will result in a HTTP `GET` request. The only valid values of a form's `method` in HTML5 are "get" and "post".

```
<form method="get" action="foo.html">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

This is the same as your example, but valid; and is equivalent to:

```
<a href="foo.html">
```

You should use semantics to determine which way to implement your form. Since there are no form fields for the user to fill in, this isn't really a form, and thus you need not use `<form>` to get the effect.

An example of when to use a `GET` form is a search box:

```
<form action="/search">
    <input type="search" name="q" placeholder="Search" value="dog">
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

The above allows the visitor to input their own search query, whereas this anchor element does not:

```
<a href="/search?q=dog">Search for "dog"</a>
```

Yet both will go to the same page when submitted/clicked (assuming the user doesn't change the text field in the first

---

As an aside, I use the following CSS to get links that look like buttons:

```
button,
.buttons a {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 9.75pt;  /* maximum size in WebKit to get native look buttons without using zoom */
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
.buttons a {
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 3px 6px 3px;
    border: 2px outset buttonface;
    background-color: buttonface;
    color: buttontext;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-appearance: button;
}
button img,
.buttons a img {
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    -ms-user-drag: none;
}
.buttons form {
    display: inline;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: @DavidPassmore: Since I never heard of it, I tried to find it.. HTML 4.01 spec certainly doesn't define it, and the MDN doesnt' mention it either. Where is this defined?

Answer (score 4):

The second case will not handle addition input arguments inside A tag. It will follow href only while form will add all inputs to request GET string.

```
<form action='http://localhost/?' method='get'><input type="text" name="test"><input type="submit" value="GO"/></form>
```

and

```
<a href='http://localhost/?'><input type="text" name="test"><input type="submit" value="GO"/></a>
```

would work different

Comment: Thanks. And if I don't need arguments, which one should I prefer? (Mainly for the compatibility)

Comment: If you need just clickable button, use anchor styled with CSS or button with onclick. If it behaves like a form with inputs, use form.

Comment: But anyway, @Nicholas is right, correct method for this is get.

Answer (score 2):

**Differences in functionality.**

While yes, they both behave somewhat like one another, there's still some reasons to use elements for what they're meant for. For the most part, you lose functionality with a button link; you cannot right click and open in a new tab or window, for example.

Consider semantics and specs as well: The button element (whichever variation you use; `<input type="button">` or `<button></button>`) was meant for use by forms.

Answer (score 1):

With a `<a name="markname"></a>` you can scroll the position of that tag into view by using the URL e.g. `http://example.com/index.html#markname`. I don't think that either form or input do so. And I think that for using `<input type="button" window.location.href='foo.html'/>`, JavaScript would have to be activated. Also, `<form>s` usually cause a line break, `<a>s` don't.

Answer (score 0):

All the mentioned methods achieve the same result, except if they contain multiple arguments, such as:

```
<input type="button" value="Cancel">
<input type="button" value="Submit">
```

For reference I use:

```
<form>
<INPUT TYPE='button' onClick="parent.location='location'">
</form>
```

For a button link