# Words after question mark is missing when click button to open link

Tags: php

This is my code:

```
$gateway = "http://html.net/page.php?name=Joe";

<form action="<?php echo $gateway ?>" method="LINK" target="_blank">
<input type="submit" value="Open link"> </input></form>
```

However, when the link is open, the URL brings me to `http://html.net/page.php` only.
How can I make it bring me to that gateway link?

Comment: `method=link` is not valid. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582286/form-method-link-or-a-whats-the-difference

Comment: Escape the ? In the string assignment

Comment: @Rhea Since when does ? need to be escaped?

Comment: You're likely looking for `method="POST"` or `method="GET"`

Comment: Link or form? You mention about `link` in your post, but you have form code.

Comment: @invisal it is a link button which in a form.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you. The solution is 
<a href="foo.html" ><input type="button" /></a>

Answer (score 0):

You have to specifically encode your GET variables in as hidden form fields.

```
<?php
$gateway = 'http://html.net/page.php?name=Joe';
$parsedUrl = parse_url($gateway);
$query = $parsedUrl['query'];
parse_str($query, $parsedQuery);
?>
<form action="<?= $gateway ?>" method="get" target="_blank">
    <div>
<?php
foreach ($parsedQuery as $key => $value) {
?>
        <input type="hidden" name="<?= $key ?>" value="<?= $value ?>" />
<?php
}
?>
        <input type="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```