# HTML button - action?

Tags: html, button

I would like to make a navigate button: **http://tulyita.hu/pr2info.php?name=** + PR2name.text

What i write wrong?

```
Enter your PR2 name: <input type="text" name="PR2name"><br>
<form method="link" action="http://tulyita.hu/pr2info.php?name=" + PR2name><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>
```

Comment: your input field `PR2name` should be inside the `<form>`

Comment: What is `PR2name`? You can't just write a variable to the markup.

Comment: `link` is not a valid value for `method` attribute of HTML `form` element, please see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp

Answer (score 3):

the `method`attribute of the form tag can only tag the value of either "get" or "post".

See this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp) for explanation.

Your code should look like:

```
<form method="get" action="http://tulyita.hu/pr2info.php">
    Enter your PR2 name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `Javascript`.

```
var val = document.getElementsByTagName('input[type="text"]').value;
```

Then pass the val to form.

Also you should also check this about `method` attribute.

`method` attribute [**`<form method=“link” > or <a>? What's the difference?`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582286/form-method-link-or-a-whats-the-difference)

> There is no **`method="LINK"`** value. This will cause the form to fall back
>   to the default method, GET, which is equivalent to an anchor element
>   with a href attribute anyway.