# is there any alternated method for anchor tag?(Deleted)

Tags: html, anchor

This is my sample html page where i'm using anchor tag inside  but i need any alternate method instead of anchor tag,could anybody tell me.

```
<body>
    <table><tr><td>
                <a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools.com!
                    <div></div>
                </a>
            </td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: ***Why*** an alternative. What are you trying to accomplish that an anchor doesn't do?

Comment: for my application it may give some problem so i need it.

Comment: What you are saying doesn't make any sense. Anchor tags are links and they need an href attribute to know where to direct the browser. If you need another attribute you can use data-attributes http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Comment: *"...There's no escaping reason, no denying purpose, because as we both know, without purpose, we would not exist..."* [(From Matrix)](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/The_Matrix_Reloaded#Dialogue) **The Anchor Tag exists for a purpose.**

Comment: *"May give some problem..."*?! What problem could that possibly be? Maybe the `<html>` tag will "give some problem" too, want to replace it as well? Maybe writing a webpage "will give some problem" too, maybe you'll want to print a poster instead?

Comment: what i mean is :without using <a></a> tags i need the same functionality if available.

Comment: Then: no. Nothing has the *same* functionality as `<a>` without `<a>`. You'll have to be a lot more specific for other possibly suggestions, but as is this question makes no sense.

Comment: @Thaz, I am sure that your application will be no different from virtually all other applications. Just use the tags the way they are intended.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Maybe you could use:

```
<form method="GET" action="foo.html">
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The difference between those two methods: [<form method="link" > or <a>? What's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582286/form-method-link-or-a-whats-the-difference)

Comment: I don't really do html xD I just thought something like that might work?

Comment: Did you actually read that thread? Especially the first and accepted answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11582427/1355315 ??

Comment: Sorry.. xD Changed it so now it should be right?

Comment: if i have 10 anchor tags inside tr,one anchor tag per td.in first td:<a id="One_i" href="javascript:GotoPage('http://www.w3schools.com','abefgcd','null','google123','1')">
                 <div></div>
                    </a> and in second td <a id="One_i"href="javascript:GotoPage('https://www.facebook.com','abcd','null','google','0')">       <div></div>
                    </a>,then how can i apply with form