# wordpress - pie register: I am trying to add a button to the login form

Tags: php, html, wordpress, button, plugins

I have been trying to add a button to pie register's login form by adding the following code in the plugins/pie-register/login_form.php file

```
$form_data .= '<form method="link" action="'.pie_registration_url().'">
               <input type="submit" id="login-create-acct" value="Create Your Free Account" /></form>'
```

Basically, instead of their register link, I would like to add a create account button.

The button appears on the form no problem. However, when I click it, instead of linking to the registration form, it instead thinks that I am attempting to login and gives me an "invalid login details" message.

all help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: `<form method="link"` that should either be `post` or `get`, not `link`, unless there's something I'm not aware of.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however, this did not solve the issue. I tried changing to both "get" and "post" to no avail. Still getting "invalid login" message.

Comment: You're welcome. Any way to see more code, including what's inside `pie_registration_url()` function? I posted an answer below. Have you looked at it?

Comment: Also, instead of `action="'.pie_registration_url().'"` have you tried using the file itself `action="handler.php"` or just doing `action=""` if your entire code is inside the same page.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may have stumbled on this link (or another page with the same "link" method):
 - http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/buttons/article.php/3478871

which contains (from what I found)

```
<FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="page1.htm">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Clickable Button">
</FORM>
```

I suggest you use (or try) `<form method="post"` or `<form method="get"` depending on the method you wish to use in conjunction with the rest of your code, that isn't posted.

Code being and related to your `pie_registration_url()` function.

In using your present method and assuming you have something similar to:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
echo $name;
```

and using `Name: <input type="text" name="name">` in the form,
would translate to `http://www.example.com/page.php?name=Bob`

and would not be properly parsed by PHP.

You may need to do something like

```
<?php
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
echo $name;
```

---

Here is another finding which is related:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11582427/