# PHP Database form CSS

Tags: php, html, css, forms

I have the following code:

```
<?php
 require "dbconn.php";

 $register="SELECT * from register WHERE username = '". $_SESSION['username']."'";

$re = $connect->query($register);

$numrow = $re->num_rows; 

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo"<th>Username</th>";
echo"<th>Forename</th>";
echo"<th>Surname</th>";
echo"<th>Course</th>";
echo"<th>Subject</th>";
echo"<th>Level</th>";
echo"<th>Date</th>";
echo"<th>Time</th>";
echo"</tr>";

$count = 0;
while ($count < $numrow) 
{
$row = $re->fetch_assoc();
extract($row);    
echo "<tr>";

echo "<td>";
echo $username;
echo "</td>";

echo "<td>";
echo $firstName;
echo "</td>";

echo "<td>";
echo $surname;
echo "</td>";

echo "<td>";
echo $course;
echo "</td>";

echo "<td>";
echo $subject;
echo "</td>";

echo "<td>";
echo $level;
echo "</td>";

echo "<td>";
echo $date;
echo "</td>";

echo "<td>";
echo $time;
echo "</td>";

echo "</tr>";

$count = $count + 1;
}

?>
```

It shows the records from the database as a form. I have the following button:

```
<FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="register.php">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Go back to register"></INPUT></form>
```

No matter what DIV I put the button in, or what CSS I give it. The button always stays ABOVE the form from the database and I cannot get it below the table.

Any ideas?

Comment: It would help if you posted the complete code becsause there is no indication of where the form element is in relation to the db output. A quick and dirty fix is to put the submit button in a table footer.

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582286/form-method-link-or-a-whats-the-difference Don't think there is a method called "LINK"

Comment: The link isn't the problem and irrelevant to the question..the form is under $count = $count + 1;
} and in the same div. If I put it in another div the result is still the same. Yeah that could work but was wondering if there is a nicer way

Comment: You *must* put `session_start()` at the top of every page your expect to use the `$_SESSION()` array.

Comment: `<input />` is an empty element and should not have a closing tag. I don't think that's your problem though. If the code is indeed below the ending of your PHP code, there should be no reason for it to not be below the table, unless you have some CSS you're not sharing.

Comment: Yes I am aware of the session start. That is not the problem. I have a whole web page which I'm not going to copy and paste as it's not needed. I have only shown RELEVANT INFORMATION. But no there is no other CSS

Comment: I can't fit in enough 9's for *99.99999999999 times out of a 100*, OP's say: *It's loaded Sam!* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: *Yeeehaw Ralph!* @Fred-ii-

Comment: Thanks for your useful informatiion...

Comment: So... put your form after the PHP?

Comment: ^ what do you think *Sam?* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: Like I said. After the PHP. In the PHP. In the DIV. Out of the DIV. It stays the same

Comment: You're going to need to show us the exact placement you're using it in your code then. You posted your PHP and your HTML apart from it and we've no way of knowing how it's being used. Plus, if you've any JS/Ajax to share with that piece of code; please do.

Comment: Plus, I don't see a closing `</table>` tag. That'll do some nasty tricks.

Comment: Oh, in regards to `METHOD="LINK"` read the following http://stackoverflow.com/a/11582427/ - there is no "method=link". You either want to use `method="post"` or "get".

Comment: Yeah I know about the link I've changed that. But you have solved it thank you. It was because the table wasn't closed

Comment: Great and you're welcome David, would you like me to post that as answer then? Along about the bit for method=link.

Comment: Sure go for it  and i'll accept it

Comment: It has been done David, *cheers*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you did not close your table with a `</table>` tag; it's important that you do.

Then there's `METHOD="LINK"` which doesn't exist and isn't a valid method.

You either want to use `method="post"` or `method="get"`.

See this answer on Stack about it:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11582427/