# Is it symantically incorrect to use "form controls" and organizers without an enclosing form?

Tags: html, forms

My question stems from the context of a web application, rather than a web page. In that context it often does not make any sense to submitt data. You want to modify state in your application using controls.

To me, it then does not make any sense to use a form. However I still need controls/widgets to modify. Meaning I need tags such as input, which I understand is a "form control", indicating that they should always be contained inside a form. Furthermore I want to organize my controls in fieldset tags.

So I was left wondering if I now have to wrap all of my controls in form-tags, even though this to me seems symantically incorrect (since I'm not going to submit).

After a few quick searches I found the two following two breif forum discussions on topic:

1. http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum21/8837.htm
2. http://doctype.com/can-fieldset-outside-form

To sum them up, using form controls outside of a form will validate on w3c. However rendering might not work in really old browsers (like Netscape 4, which I really don't care about.)

In the first link there seems to be support for using form controls outside of forms as the symantically correct thing to do in my sort of scenario. However in the other it seems that using fieldsets should strictly be done within a form when caring about being symantically correct.

Does this mean I should feel free to use controls outside of forms, but I must wrap them in divs rather than fieldsets, or should I read this some other way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is <input> well formed without a <form>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294572/is-input-well-formed-without-a-form)

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela that post supports my first link, but doesn't discuss fieldsets.

Comment: I though it was evident that whatever applies to `input` in this regard applies to other “form controls” and their grouping, too.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Maybe it is evident. It certainly seems to logically follow. But when dealing with specs I've learned to take nothing for granted. I do believe what seems evident is actually the case for this issue. See my below answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html) states:

17.2.1 Control types

> The elements used to create controls generally appear inside a FORM element, but may also appear outside of a FORM element declaration when they are used to build user interfaces. This is discussed in the section on intrinsic events. Note that controls outside a form cannot be successful controls.

17.10 Adding structure to forms: the FIELDSET and LEGEND elements

> The FIELDSET element allows authors to group thematically related controls and labels.

17.10 doesn't make any mention of the form element, to me this means that there is no limitation on where it can be used except that it should surround controls and labels. 17.10.2 Seems to allow me to use those outside of a form. Hence I can also use the fieldset outside of a form, as long as it wraps controls and labels.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across use cases where I have required to have form controls without the need for actually submitting the form.

Sometimes, enclosing within the  tag only makes the things worse, because I might be interested in calling a JS function whereas the form simply submits and reloads the page. I have encountered this using PhoneGap application on a WindowsPhone.

As for me, I wouldn't be too bothered about W3C validation, given it makes life much more simpler.