# Input elements independent of forms

Tags: html

My question is if an input element in HTML exists which is **independent of form element** (not INPUT or TEXTAREA). Are there any?

Greez
tomi

Comment: all elements are independent

Comment: You can use elements like INPUT or TEXTAREA outside of form. If you have an inherent despise for them, you can also try DIV with `contebteditable` set to `true`

Comment: Neither `input` or `textarea` _have_ to be inside a `form` … (if that’s what you’re asking – quite unclear what you actually want to know here).

Comment: I think what you intended to ask was already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3294624/2186023

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think so, only declare the input inside of form, always for declare input type text should be inside of form html, you can read more about this...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input