# What is the benefit for using "form" tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I don't understand what is the benefit of using `<form>` tag.

Look at the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function check(browser) {
    document.getElementById("answer").value=browser;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>What's your favorite browser ?</p>

<form>
<input type="radio" name="browser" onclick="check(this.value)" value="Internet Explorer">Internet Explorer<br>
<input type="radio" name="browser" onclick="check(this.value)" value="Firefox">Firefox<br>
<input type="radio" name="browser" onclick="check(this.value)" value="Opera">Opera<br>
<input type="radio" name="browser" onclick="check(this.value)" value="Google Chrome">Google Chrome<br>
<input type="radio" name="browser" onclick="check(this.value)" value="Safari">Safari<br>
<br>
Your favorite browser is: <input type="text" id="answer" size="20">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

If I'm removing the tags: "form" and "/form"
I'm getting the same results. so what is the different ?

Thanks

Comment: You use the form tag when you want to not use JavaScript and submit a collection of form fields to a script on your server. In your example the form element would not be needed.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Comment: Although you don't have the usual perk of having  a form(easy submit to server), you can still use it to make your markup semantic.

Comment: Form is an HTML tag which is basically being used to submit all the editor template contents.

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294572. Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If I'm removing the tags: "form" and "/form" I'm getting the same
>   results

Yes. At client site.

Try to post it to a server. You *won't* be able to read anything at the server side.

In other words , if you add :

```
<input type="submit" />
```

The server won't know how to read those values.

Form posts its inputs values (+ select , textarea etc...) to a server. *Then* you can read those values at the server side.

*Other benefits/features*

- Giving a name to a `form` allows you to access its child inputs via their name : `alert(myForm.myUserInputName)`
- You can cause the post to yield its result/response in other iframe/location using `target` property.
- You can cause the page to post itself via GET and not via POST  , which will cause all input values to be as QueryString.

Answer (score 1):

It's used to provide meaning to the browser and the developer

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp

> Semantics is the study of the meanings of words and phrases in
>   language.
>
> Semantic elements are elements with a meaning.

It's also used when you want to "submit" the form as GET/POST for example, to save data to a database.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can set the calling action as an attribute in the form tag.

Then there is another attribute "method" which decides if it is an get- or post-request.

You may also have multiple forms on your website and just want to sent the data within the form tag.

```
<form id="form1" action="http://localhost/urlone" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="field1" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<form id="form2" action="http://localhost/urltwo" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="field2" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

If you click the first submit button form1 will be send with the field1 as a get request. If you click the second button. form2 will be sent as an post request.

Hope it helps to understand.

Comment: Though allowed, there is no closing slash on input tags and they are ignored by everything.

Comment: In xhtml you have to close every tag. But in e.g. html5 it is not required. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

Form tags are used to 'submit' data to the application that is controlling the form behaviour: for example, if you had a registration form, you would have a back-end language that would 'accept' the data from the form and then store it in a database.

For the language to be able to accept the data, form tags are required because they have the 'action' attribute.

Also, when you have form tags, the user can press Enter to submit it.

And as Kevin P. said, they are also semantically useful.