# Semantics of HTML element that acts on `input`

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I have a set of `checkboxes` with the following structure:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="a1"/>A1</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="a2"/>A2</label>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

The checkboxes are only used for UI control (not for a form submission). I have an associated html element that has an `onclick` jQuery function that clears all the checkboxes.  This element is currently just a `div`. Semantically, are there any best practices to say whether this should be a `button`, an `a` (with no `href` value) or continue to be a `div`?

Comment: Well... it should technically be part of the form itself, and be a checkbox, really (on or off for select all / deselect all). If it relies on javascript, it should be added using javascript (not part of the HTML at all). Also, I hope those checkboxes are wrapped in a `<form>`-tag.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie - no, they're not wrapped in a `<form>` tag (I didn't write the HTML...), but thanks for the tip about the fact it should be added by javascript itself - I agree with that!

Comment: Well, then it's already non-semantic, so who cares about what element you use. Just add it via javascript, if it's based on that for functionality.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie I accept this uses HTML4, but http://stackoverflow.com/a/3294624/889604 implies that a `form` tag isn't needed - has this changed for HTML5?

Comment: I thought it was for submitting. If it's just for UI controls, a form isn't strictly needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a [`button` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/sec-forms.html#the-button-element) in the [`button` state](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/sec-forms.html#element-statedef-button-type-button) (or an [`input` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/sec-forms.html#elementdef-input) in the [`button` state](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/sec-forms.html#element-statedef-input-button)).

**Why not [`a`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/textlevel-semantics.html#the-a-element)?** Because it should only be used for links to resources.

**Why not [`div`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/grouping-content.html#the-div-element)?** Because it isn’t focusable by default (for keyboard users), and because it doesn’t come with an implicit WAI-ARIA role (for accessibility), so you would have to add both features manually, essentially recreating an element that already exists: `button`.

Comment: This is actually what I originally thought, thanks for the confirmation

Answer (score 1):

Semantics is a dying dodo bird. Having said that here's my attempt to meet standards that seem to be largely ignored. I just use whatever element is best suited for the task and seems logical, generic divs and spans being the last to be considered. I believe keeping code from presentation and markup was a major objective as well, so use `addEventListener` instead of attribute event handlers like `onclick`

#### SNIPPET

```js
var allchx = document.getElementById('allChecks');

allchx.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  this.checked ? checkUncheck(true) : checkUncheck(false);
}, false);

function checkUncheck(chxBool) {
  var chxList = document.querySelectorAll('input[name^="question"]');
  var qty = chxList.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < qty; i++) {
    chxList[i].checked = chxBool;
  }
}
```

```html
<form id='survey' name='survey' action='http://httpbin.org/post' method='post'>
  <fieldset class='checkboxSet'>
    <legend>Product Survey</legend>
    <label for='allChecks'>
      <input id='allChecks' type='checkbox'>Check/Uncheck All</label>
    <hr/>
    <ol>
      <li>
        <label for='question1'>
          <input id='question1' name='question1' type='checkbox' value='smoker'>Do you smoke?</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for='question2'>
          <input id='question2' name='question2' type='checkbox' value='lard eater'>Do you eat lard?</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for='question3'>
          <input id='question3' name='question3' type='checkbox' value='potential customer'>Do you have explosive diareha?</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for='question4'>
          <input id='question4' name='question4' type='checkbox' value='definite customer'>Would you be interested in having explosive diareha in the near future?</label>
      </li>
    </ol>
    <input type='submit'>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Useful perspective, thanks (and although I said `onclick`, it's jQuery and so totally separated from the tags anyway)

Comment: If you use `onclick` method, there's only 2 ways to use it AFAIK: as an element attribute or as a DOM property to which both are plain JavaScript methods. I looked for it in jQuery but `.on('click'...` is not `onclick`.

Comment: I was using the phrase `onclick` as a description, rather than as a technical term.  I'm not using an `onclick`, just a very simple click function: `$("#clearboxes").click(function(){ /*logic to clear boxes*/ });`