# Data transfer between 2 pages. Other page prefilled

Tags: javascript, local-storage, html

This is the book now button from page 1, product.html

```html
 <form name="booksr1" method="link" action="enquiry.html"><input type="button" value="Book Now" class="book" onclick="window.location.href='enquiry.html'" /></form>
```

I'd like to make it where the other page, enquiry.html is prefilled with the subject I want e.g. RE: Enquiry on: Single Room, when the "Book Now" button on the other page is clicked on

This is the code for the RE: Enquiry input on page 2.

```html
<label for="RE: Enquiry on:">RE: Enquiry on:<span class="RequiredColor">*</span></label><br/>
<input type="text" id="Subject"/><br/><br/>
```

How should I do this with localstorage?

P.S. I'm quite new to this so please make it simple to understand. THANKS!!!

Comment: `method="link"` is not valid HTML (just `get`, `post` and `dialog` are valid). See the [official spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-form-method). Also, if you don't submit the `form` you can actually skip it: A `<input>` [is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53221899/5247200) without `<form>`.

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow doesn't allow you to save/read from localStorage, so you can't click the buttons to see it work, but let's give this a go. There might be some errors, it's late, but I hope I can explain.

Let's say you have `product.html`:

```js
function go() {
  var room = document.querySelector('#room-select').value;
  localStorage.setItem('room', room);
  location.href="enquiry.html";
}
```

```html
<label for="room-select">Choose a Room:</label>

<select id="room-select">
    <option value="1">Single Room</option>
    <option value="2">Double Room</option>
    <option value="3">Triple Room</option>
</select>

<button onclick="go()">Submit</button>
```

You run a function that gets the value of the select box, stores it in localStorage and then goes to your enquiry page.

Now you have to add some script to `enquiry.html` to read the value back out.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    var room = localStorage.getItem('room');
    var input = document.querySelector('#subject');
    input.value = room;
});
```

```html
<label for="subject">RE: Enquiry on:</label>
<input type="text" id="subject" name="name" required>
```

You have to wait for the page to load (listen for the event `DOMContentLoaded`), then read the value you stored on the previous page, get a reference to the input box and update its value with the one you read from storage.

Comment: i've encountered a new problem, can you please help me again? :)

Answer (score 0):

****LATEST UPDATE*** 
I've added and editted the codes Will suggested(Thanks!! :D) into my product.html,

```html
function room1() {
 var room = document.querySelector('#room-selector-one').value;
 localStorage.setItem("booking1", "Single Room(Fan)");
 location.href="enquiry.html";
}

function room2() {
    var room = document.querySelector('#room-selector-two').value;
 localStorage.setItem("booking2","Single Room(AC)");
 location.href="enquiry.html";
}
```

and my enquiry.html.

```html
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    var room = localStorage.getItem('booking1');
    var input = document.querySelector('#subject');
 input.value = room;    
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    var room = localStorage.getItem('booking2');
    var input = document.querySelector('#subject');
 input.value = room;    
});
```

But now, there's a new problem. I'm able to run the first product value to the enquiry.html page but when after i edited the second product codes, when i try to click back to the button on product.html for the first product, the second value still remains.

Comment: Looks like we need to clear up a misunderstanding. `product.html` only needs one function. You trigger the function (presumably on a button-click), read the form value and save it to localStorage. You don't need one function per 'answer'. On the `enquiry.html` page, again, you only need one function. It waits for the page to load and reads the previous choice from storage. Does that make sense?

Comment: The disconnect might be because I used a `select` drop-down and you might be using buttons? If that's the case, you can use multiple functions (probably better to use a single function with a parameter), but you wouldn't need to do the `querySelector` part because you'd already know which room was selected.