# How to call the JQUERY click() method when pressing Enter on the keyboard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, enter

I created a search form and I set a function which tells the browser to display a JSON file whenever a string is entered on the text field and the button `Search` is pressed:

```
$("#IDofTheSearchButton").on('click', function);
```

I want to call the same function also whenever the input field is filled up and the user presses the Button `Enter` on the keyboard.

How can I do that?

- - - - E D I T  [ S O L V E D ]- - - -

I edit the code as in the following, by exploiting the `keydown` event listener, and it works now:

```
$('#IDofTheInputField').on('keydown', function(e) {

            if (e.which == 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                nameOfTheFunction();
            }
        } );
```

I also added the `preventDefault()` method to prevent the `Enter` key to activate the `Submit` event (otherwise, the code doesn't work for this specific key).

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_trigger_button_enter.asp

Answer (score 4):

By adding the 'keydown' eventlistener on the input box you will be able to call the function. The 13 stands for the 'Enter' key.

```js
$('#inputExample').on('keydown',function(e) {
    // You could use e.which == 13, but .which has been deprecated
    if(e.key == 'Enter') {
        // You could use the .click() function below, but it is better to call the function directly.
        // $("#submitButton").click();
        someFunction();
    }
});

$('#submitButton').on('click', someFunction);

function someFunction(){
  alert("Function has been called")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inputExample" type="text">

<button id="submitButton" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Bonus points for calling the method directly instead of triggering a click.

Comment: Thank you for answering. You wrote that the 13 stands for the 'Enter' key: where may I find the whole map for the keys of the keyboard? I have not a US keyboard and the code does not work for me...

Comment: Minor point: the submit button part could be simplified even further to `$('#submitButton').click(someFunction);`

Comment: @franz1, you could find the complete mapping [here](https://keycode.info/) and [here](http://gcctech.org/csc/javascript/javascript_keycodes.htm)

Comment: @Dontwan,   the method you mentioned is the correct one but I had to add the `e.preventDefault()`. Otherwise the default event associated to the key `Enter` (submit) is activated as well and the code doesn't work...

Comment: @franz1 This is because you may have placed the input within <form> tags?

Comment: The <form> tags will be useless because you are not going to send any data to a server (ajax request). [<input> without a <form> tags appears to be valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294572/is-input-well-formed-without-a-form)

Comment: ok, thank you @Dontwan  . I also used the '(e.which == 13)' instead than '(e.key == 'Enter')'. Otherwise, the code doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `submit` jquery method. 
something like this

```
$("#IDofTheSearchButton").submit(function);
```

So whenever the user has finished typing and presses enter, the function will be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
 $('.input').keypress(function (e) {
      if (e.which == 13) {
        $('#IDofTheSearchButton').click();
        return false;    
      }
 });
```