# ReactJs button onClick not firing and input field does not show anything

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, button, react-hooks

I am trying to apply the following form for submission in React, but nothing is being shown in the input text field that I type. Hence the onClick does not get fired as well.

I saw a lot of posts but I could not find the solution to my issue, I'm a beginner as well.

```
    <form>
          <input
            value={input}
            onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Type a message"
          />
          <button onClick={sendMessage} type="submit">
            Send
          </button>
          {/* onClick={sendMessage} */}
        </form>
```

And the sendMessage is defined as below:

```
function Chat({ messages }) {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  const sendMessage = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await axios.post("/messages/new", {
      message: input,
      name: "Abhi",
      received: true,
      timestamp: "Just Now",
    });

    setInput("");
  };
// below contains the render return () which consists the form shown above.
```

Comment: remove `type="submit"` as you already have click handler for button

Comment: Or move `sendMessage` to the form element's `onSubmit` handler, i.e. `<form onSubmit={sendMessage}> ....`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Form elements don't require `form`. As long as your form elements are contained it's [perfectly valid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53221899/1377002) HTML. Which means you can use a `div` and remove the `e.preventDefault()` from your handler.
2. You can then remove the `type=submit` attribute from your button as it's no longer needed. Just use the `onClick` handler.
3. Perhaps use a separate handler for the input for clarity.
4. `sendMessage` probably doesn't need to be `async` as you're not returning anything from your Axios process that the state function relies on for its update, so make it a standard function instead.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Chat() {

  const [ input, setInput ] = useState('');

  function handleChange(e) {
    const { value } = e.target;
    console.log(value);
    setInput(value);
  }

  function sendMessage() {
    console.log(`Final state: ${input}`);
    // AXIOS here
    setInput('');
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        value={input}
        onChange={handleChange}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Type a message"
      />
      <button onClick={sendMessage}>Send</button>
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Chat />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```